# Can only send emails when using IP of SMTP host

Tags: c#, email, smtp, ip

I have this annoying issue:

1. When sending an email when debugging in VS, it works fine (I'm using `SmtpClient`)
2. After publishing to the server, I get this error:

   > System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mail.company.co.za'
3. However, if I change the smtp host to the IP address, it seems to work fine.

I got the IP by calling `ping mail.company.co.za` in CMD (When calling this on the server it can't find the address, **but it can ping the IP**)

Since I'm not sure whether the IP is static or not, I don't know if its safe to just use the physical IP. Why would the server not recognise the `mail.company.co.za`?

Note that I am debugging and hosting the application on the same network. This suggests to me that it is not a firewall issue, but maybe I'm wrong about that?

Comment: There is an issue with DNS on the server. The bug is not in your software. Can you resolve other addresses like google.com or whatever, just any?

Comment: @Fildor I can resolve other addresses, yes The `mail.company.co.za` is being hosted by some service provider

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like your code is working properly, but you mailserver's DNS is not set up properly. Your PC can correctly look up the address, but the mailserver cannot.

Fixing this is a server admin question, not a coding question, but if you don't have IT people to do it for you, I suggest just finding the 'DNS Server' setting in your network setup and copying the settings from your PC to the server. Windows tends to change how you get to these settings with every version, but for me it's Control Panel / Network and Sharing / Ethernet / TCPIP / Properties

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

- Open Control Panel.
- Click on Network and Internet.
- Click on Network and Sharing Center.
- On the left pane, click on Change adapter settings.
- Right-click the network interface connected to the  internet, and select Properties.
- Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) from the list.
- Click the Properties button.
- Click the Use the following DNS server addresses option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robin. Do you happen to know where I can find these DNS servrs on my computer?

Comment: @Bassie I've added a link to some instructions

Comment: My laptop has it set to automatically obtain, but the server is pointing at some local address (10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3) I don't want to change those as those are the addresses we use for a couple of things. I'll have to check with someone who knows about this stuff